# How to test a component with subscription

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, subscription

Unit test with Subscription in a component with Jasmine/Karma
Im trying to test if metatags are well generated by ngOninit in my page :

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.pagesSub = this.pagesService.initPage().subscribe();
  }
```

This is my InitPage function :

```
initPage(): Observable<Page> {
    return this.pageDbService.data$.pipe(
      map((pages: Page[]) => {
        let currentPage: Page;
        if (pages.length > 0) {
          this.setPagesToStore(pages);
          if (this.router.url === '/') {
            currentPage = pages[0]
          } else {
            currentPage = pages.find(page => ('/' + page.pageId) === this.router.url)
          }
        } else {
          this.setPagesToStore(pagesSeed);
          if (this.router.url === '/') {
            currentPage = pagesSeed[0]
          } else {
            currentPage = pagesSeed.find(page => ('/' + page.pageId) === this.router.url)
          }
        }
        this.seoService.generatePageTags(currentPage);
        return currentPage;
      })
    )
  }
```

And this is the generatePageTags function :

```
generatePageTags(page: Page) {
    const pageTitle = `${page.pageTitle} - IZIprint`;
    this.titleService.setTitle(pageTitle);
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'robots', content: 'index,follow' });
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: page.description });
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:type', content: 'website' });
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:title', content: page.socialTitle });
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:description', content: page.description });
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:url', content: page.ogUrl });
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:image', content: page.socialImage.thumbUrl });
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:determiner', content: 'auto' });
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:locale', content: 'fr_FR' });
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:site_name', content: 'IZIprint' });
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'twitter:card', content: 'summary_large_image' });
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'twitter:title', content: page.socialTitle });
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'twitter:description', content: page.description });
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'twitter:image', content: page.socialImage.thumbUrl });
  }
```

If I test with this test :

```
  it(`should have a metatag property="og:site_name" with content='IZIprint'`, fakeAsync(() => {
    meta = TestBed.inject(Meta);
    component.ngOnInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    flush();
    expect(meta.getTag('property="og:site_name"').content).toBe('IZIprint');
  }));
```

Jasmine-Karma does not find the content of 'property="og:site_name"' in my page.
I am new to testing. Where is my mistake please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a proper mock for the `pageDbService.data$.` the code bellow should be enough:

```js
it(`should have a metatag property="og:site_name" with content='IZIprint'`, async () => {
  component.ngOnInit();
  await fixture.whenStable()

  meta = TestBed.inject(Meta);
  expect(meta.getTag('property="og:site_name"').content).toBe('IZIprint');
});
```

`fixture.detectChanges();` triggers the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook. No need to call it them both. `detectChanges` also triggers change detection and rendering. This test doesn't depend on either of those. `ngOnInit` would be enough.

The issue is the `pageDbService.data$` mock. I don't see the code for it, so I can not say if this mock setup correctly.